Basic Question on GRPC client side proto message to server
I am fairly new to GRPC and Protobuf, but i wanted to understand that if it is possible to define a message on client side in protobuf and send it to a GRPC golang server RPC i.e the server can just unmarshal the proto and respond with say "accepted" ?
i have read through the GRPC and Protobuf doc, but in the doc the service and message are defined together

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Yes, you can do this but gRPC uses Protobuf for type-ful messsages and it's not possible to always perfectly introspect a message schema from a message.
You essentially want to embed arbitrary messages in a (defined) message that the client|server share:
syntax = "proto3";

service Foo {
  rpc Send(SendRequest) returns (SendResponse);
}

You have options for SendRequest (and SendResponse):

Any but this requires an out-of-band repository of the message types
JSON with the knowledge that this is typeless

as a Protobuf string or bytes (see scalar)
as a Struct


Some other type

